# What's the difference between -rpath and -L?

Tags: gcc, ld

The GNU Compiler Collection (aka gcc) and ld provide many ways to specify a search path for libraries—among them the `-rpath` and `-L` flags. The manpages reveal no differences between these two flags, effectively saying each flag adds a library to the library search path. Yet it seems strange that both flags do *exactly* the same thing. What are the differences, if any, between these two options?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of `-rpath-link`?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You must be reading some outdated copies of the manpages (emphasis added):

> -rpath=dir
>         Add a directory to the **runtime** library search path.  This is used
>         when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.  All -rpath
>         arguments are concatenated and passed to the **runtime** linker, which
>         uses them to locate shared objects at **runtime.**

vs.

> -L searchdir
>   --library-path=searchdir
>         Add path searchdir to the list of paths that **ld** will search for
>         archive libraries and ld control scripts.

So, `-L` tells `ld` where to look for libraries to link against when linking. You use this (for example) when you're building against libraries in your build tree, which will be put in the normal system library paths by `make install`. `--rpath`, on the other hand, stores that path inside the executable, so that the runtime dynamic linker can find the libraries. You use this when your libraries are outside the system library search path.

Comment: Notes: 1. Most of the time when one needs `-rpath=/some/weird/path`, one needs `-L /some/weird/path` too. 2. With `gcc` one needs use `-Wl,-rpath=dir`.

Comment: I still don't understand why both are needed. I have the same experience as n.m. above. What information is needed from the library at build time? Apart from possible h-files, of cause. But that's another thing I guess...

Comment: @FredrikJohansson That'd be a reasonable subject for a new question (presuming it hasn't already been asked, of course). The available symbols are needed, at least, but there are probably other things.

Comment: Followup question added at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096133/why-is-l-needed-when-rpath-is-used

Comment: @n.m. For `gcc`, once `-Wl, -rpath` is used for all the libraries, then `-L` could be omitted.

Comment: @John Not in my experience.