# "symbol lookup error: ...: undefined symbol" (Qwt) Should I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linux, qt, qwt

After installing qwt-6.1.2.zip I see it at:

```
/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib/libqwt.so
```

The Qt app I'm developing depends on in, so the .pro has the following:

```
    INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/include"
    LIBS += -L"/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib"
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -lqwtd
    } else {
        LIBS += -lqwt
    }
```

It compiles well but executing (outside QtCreator) gives:

```
"symbol lookup error: ...: undefined symbol"
```

Which is solved by doing:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If I understand it correctly, [LD_LIBRARY_PATH should only be set in case the .so files are in exotic (non-standard) locations](http://www.unixresources.net/linux/lf/48/archive/00/00/03/87/38791.html). Question, `/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib` is standard (I guess not)?

When and where should LD_LIBRARY_PATH be set? I think one option is to do that at installation time, something like:

```
echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib" >> .bashrc
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> .bashrc
```

One downside of this is that multiple installations will write that stuff multiple times to .bashrc.

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l) and actually I ended up using the `-rpath` idea, but I think the context here could be seen as more specific, related to Qt, so isn't duplicate. In fact, I ended up using [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40128-How-to-set-rpath-in-Qt-Project).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between -rpath and -L?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l)

Answer (score 2):

For your given use case it seems like you shouldn't be using LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Instead, you should add a configuration file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and the run `ldconfig`.

For example as root run the following commands:

```
echo "/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/qwt.conf
ldconfig
```

`ldconfig` creates information required for dynamically linked programs to resolve where the libraries are located. The configuration file created tells `ldconfig` to search in the specified directory for more libraries to include in its database of shared libraries. This allows programs to use the shared library without have to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable because it is now a *standard* library.

Comment: Didn't tried this (found another solution, as edit at the end of the question), but in this case what will happen if another version of Qwt is already installed (at /usr/lib/libqwt.so)?