# How to use the correct libstdc++ ?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libstdc++

I've just compiled the **trunk version of gcc** but when using g++ to compile a c++ project I see that standard library components that should be there, like `std::conjunction`, are missing. When I check the code in the my local repository (`gcc_trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/std`), everything seems to be there. How can I ensure I'm using the correct version of **`libstdc++`** ?

Below are some commands I've used to check the system with their respective output

> $ readelf -d /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep soname

```
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libstdc++.so.6]
```

> $ ls -l  /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 7 13:19 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.23
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've installed new GCC to some non-standard location (i.e. not under `/usr`) so at runtime your app tries to use host `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so` which is incompatible. To solve this problem you can do either of

- run your app with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to point to new GCC library folder
- link your app with [-Wl,-rpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l)
- statically link with `libstdc++` via `-static-libstdc++` (this is a partial solution as other compiler libs e.g. `libgcc.so` will still come from host GCC)

Comment: But I have a compile time error, this can't be a runtime error (eg `conjunction` is not a member of std)

Comment: I suggest you provide more details in your question. E.g. atm it's unclear whether it's runtime or compile-time error...