# How to include a C++ library after I `make` it?

Tags: c++, gcc

I followed the [instructions to build `arrow`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html#building) which is

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow/cpp
mkdir release
cd release
cmake ..
make
```

so now I want to make use of the libraries I have built

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "parquet/arrow/writer.h"

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("ok")
}
```

but it complains that

```sh
In file included from /home/xiaodai/git/arrow/cpp/src/parquet/arrow/writer.h:24:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/home/xiaodai/git/arrow/cpp/src/parquet/properties.h:30:10: fatal error: parquet/parquet_version.h: No such file or directory
 #include "parquet/parquet_version.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

so how do I tell gcc to use the library I just built?

Comment: in case of distributed libraries you have to install it appropriately

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie So tips on how would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Installation

```sh
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow/cpp
mkdir release
cd release
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_path> -DARROW_PARQUET=ON
make
make install
```

Step 2. Compilation and linking

```sh
g++ main.cpp -I<install_path>/include -L<install_path>/lib -lparquet -larrow -o main
```

`main.cpp` should be fixed (`void main`, missing `;`) before you try to compile it.

> Once I compiled successful, I run `./main` and I get `./main: error while loading shared libraries: libparquet.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which is weird because `<install_path>/lib` clearly has the file `libparquet.so.18`!

The problem is that the dynamic loader cannot find the dynamic library. It doesn't know that `<install_path>/lib` should also be examined, and needs your help:

- add `<install_path>/lib` into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

  ```sh
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<install_path>/lib
  ```
- or hardcode library path into the executable (not a good idea in general) with [`rpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l) by adding `-Wl,-rpath=<install_path>/lib` to `g++` options.

Comment: can you please explain what -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_path> is for?

Comment: @xiaodai, to set the path where the library files will be copied to when you run `make install`.

Comment: Once I compiled successful, I run `./main` and I get `./main: error while loading shared libraries: libparquet.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and `ldd ./main` returns `libparquet.so.18 => not found` which is weird because `<install_path>/lib` clearly has the file `libparquet.so.18`! Any ideas?