# Using g++ to link a static library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a `Makefile` setup to build unit tests for my application:

```
test: app_test.o sdk.o
    g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --coverage -o test app_test.o sdk.o ./sdk/libNSomeLib.so.2.6 -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

I have a folder in the root of my project directory called `sdk`, which `libNSomeLib.so.2.6` is in.

When running locally, I can run `make test` and then `./test` and have the tests run.

However, I'm also running the following in Azure DevOps, as part of a build pipeline:

1. `make test`
2. `./test`

and receive:

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libNSomeLib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had initially tried "installing" this library that I need onto each system I need to run it on, and updating `ldconfig`, but it's not feasible so I decided to statically link the library instead, and include the `.so` file in the repository itself.

So why is this happening if I'm statically linking, and how would I fix it? It seems to build fine, it's just the running part that isn't working.

Comment: (1) You cannot statically link with a shared library. (2) No need to touch ldconfig. Read about `-rpath` e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l).

Comment: @n.m. So pretty much it's needed that I "install" the lib into a known path, add the directory using `-L`, and then link it using `-l`?

Comment: If you build and run on the same machine, then the library is already on that machine at a known path (otherwise you would not be able to build). Use that path as the `-rpath` argument. If you build on one machine and run on a different machine, you need to transport the library to the target machine somehow, and use `-rpath` relevant to the target machine. (You can use a path relative to the executable; read about `$ORIGIN`).

Comment: @n.m. Is there no way to embed that library into the final executable I'm trying to build?

Comment: There might be, but you don't want it. Just copy it together with the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy "test" and "sdk/libNSomeLib.so.2.6" to any machine and can excute it without ldconfig. if you dislike "sdk" dir. You should build it with

```
g++ app_test.o.sdk.o -Lsdk -lNSomeLib -o test -Wl,-rpath=.
```

after that, you place both "test" and "libNSomeLib.so" in same director and you can execute "test" because of searching .so by rpath=. option embedded in "test" executable

Comment: Should be `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`, not `.`